# Unknown error when trying to run a newly built Tezos node: tezos-node: Error: Unix error in unlink: Permission denied

Tags: node, error

I build my node via opam ( installed through the apt Ubuntu package manager ). After I download and import the snapshot and run the node for the first time it, it generates the identity as normal then soon after I run into an error that I don't understand.

Command: tezos-node run --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1 --history-mode full

```
Apr 21 15:32:11.497 - node.main: generating an identity file
Generating a new identity... (level: 26.00) |....o
Stored the new identity (xxxxxxx) into '/home/tanker/.tezos-node/identity.json'.
Apr 21 15:33:37.968 - node.main: identity file generated (peer_id = xxxxxxx)
Apr 21 15:33:37.968 - node.main: starting the Tezos node (chain = TEZOS_MAINNET)
Apr 21 15:33:37.968 - node.main: disabled local peer discovery
Apr 21 15:33:38.046 - node: shell-node initialization: bootstrapping
Apr 21 15:33:38.046 - node: shell-node initialization: p2p_maintain_started
Apr 21 15:33:38.046 - external_block_validator: initialized
(/home/xxxxx/.opam/for_tezos/bin/tezos-node) Exit: uncaught exception during clean-up (File "src/lib_shell/block_validator_process.ml", line 377, characters 48-55): Unix.Unix_error(Unix.EACCES, "unlink", "/run/user/1000/tezos-validation-socket-430016")
tezos-node: Error:
              Unix error in unlink: Permission denied

xxxxx@xxxxx-ThinkPad-xxxxx:~$ ~Fatal error: exception Unix.Unix_error(Unix.EACCES, "connect", "")
Raised by primitive operation at file "src/unix/lwt_unix.cppo.ml", line 1773, characters 10-33
Called from file "src/unix/lwt_unix.cppo.ml", line 562, characters 17-28
Re-raised at file "src/core/lwt.ml", line 3072, characters 20-29
Called from file "src/unix/lwt_main.ml", line 31, characters 10-20
Called from file "src/unix/lwt_main.ml", line 118, characters 8-13
Re-raised at file "src/unix/lwt_main.ml", line 124, characters 4-13
Called from file "src/bin_node/main.ml", line 58, characters 8-216
Re-raised at file "parsing/location.ml", line 899, characters 14-25
Called from file "format.ml", line 1264, characters 32-48
Called from file "format.ml", line 1266, characters 32-48
Called from file "format.ml", line 1313, characters 16-34
Called from file "src/bin_node/main.ml", line 64, characters 6-56
```

***after that last line it just hangs up***

Comment: `unlink` is an internal way of saying "delete". You have a permissions error somewhere such that the node cannot delete a file.

Comment: Thank you, that gives me a little more to work with.